# What rules are known for Chaturanga?

Tags: rules, history, chess-variants

In the ancient Indian game Chaturanga, what rules are known, and how does it vary from modern chess? Also, is it a solved game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact rules aren't known, but what *is* known or commonly believed to be true is listed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaturanga#Rules). Especially the elephant/gaja's movement rules are uncertain.

It varies from modern chess because it has some pieces which move differently: the elephant mentioned above and the mantri/minister. Modern chess has the bishop and queen in their places. Still, the complexity of the game is comparable to chess, so it's a long way from being solved.

Comment: What about castling & en passant?

Comment: Unlikely, those are modern inventions.

Comment: No. Castling was already present in Dashpaad board..