# Can I play chaturanga on any of the main chess sites?

Tags: history

Inspired by this question [What rules are known for Chaturanga?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/32843/what-rules-are-known-for-chaturanga)

Chaturanga seems quite interesting, and some aspects of it, like no castling are being introduced in other variants: Kramnik's chess. Given that, say, lichess.org has so many variants, is there a reason why Chaturanga is not of them?

Possible reasons:

1. The rules are not exactly known.
2. Queen (Mantri) is much less powerful and pawns don't have a 2-square move option on the first move, which makes the game less interesting / drawish to many people.
3. Strategies were developed to draw fairly easily, (and that's why rule changes were introduced). This is a stronger version of 2), and probably not likely.

Comment: The answer to my question said that the rules weren't clear, so reason number 1 is the answer.

Comment: The title is different than the question stated in body.

Comment: @fartgeek, that's true, my initial question was based on incorrect assumption that you cannot play Chaturanga on any of the main chess sites, so I edited the title after the answer. Do you think it is better to revert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered your own question, with 1) and 2) being the main causes!

I don't know about 3), tbh, but it seems at least somewhat plausible (although stalemate was also a win in chaturanga so who knows!).

You say that it's not on main chess sites, but chess.com at least has it as a playable variant- can't speak for how easily you'll find a game there however.

It's also presumably not trivial to code the game, which is probably another reason why.

Comment: I stand corrected, chess.com does have it!

Comment: I just played a few games, no problem finding opponents.

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: https://www.chess.com/variants - one of the options is Chaturanga

Comment: Chaturanga is incomplete game and people on the internet are trying to scam each other. Ashtpaad board based Chatur Yantra was the only complete game. I am fpcussing only on dashpaad as Ashtpaad based Game is not of my interest..